# AndEngine, PhysicsWorld not updating?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I have written this code multiple times before without problems. The problem is that the physics world just does not seem to be updating and I don't know why! Right now I have a gameScene class which extends a normal scene, this is the onCreate method:

```
@Override
    public void create() {


        ParallaxBackground background = new ParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0);
        background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0, new Sprite(0, 0, res.BasicBackground, res.vbom)));
        this.setBackground(background);

        test = new Sprite(0, 0, res.GrassRegion, res.vbom);
        FixtureDef fix = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10f, 0f, 10f);
        Body bod = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, test, BodyType.DynamicBody, fix);

        attachChild(test);



        physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);


        physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(test, bod, true, true));
        this.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);


    }
```

(I removed a lot of the unnecessary things)  I just have a basic test sprite to make sure that the physics is working (which it is not). The app runs without any errors, its just that the sprite will not move, leading me to think that its a problem with the physics world being update.

As you can see, I'm setting the gravity to be accelerating in both the X and Y directions. I did this because I thought maybe it wasn't working in one direction for some reason. I'm thinking that maybe I have to set the scene to update in the main activity? But I don't remember having to do that with any of my other apps. Any help is appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

No, `this.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);` will do just fine. Try adding this:

```
physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, AHC.WORLD_GRAVITY), false) {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }
};
```

And put a breakpoint or `Log.i(TAG, "hey");` inside onUpdate to check if it hits it

**EDIT:**
Try registering a "normal" `UpdateHandler`, you can do it in 2 ways:

```
public class YourGameActivity implements IUpdateHandler{
    ...

    private void yourSetupMethod(){
        registerUpdateHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {}

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        Log.i(TAG, "hey");
    }
}
```

or you can create a class that `implements IUpdateHandler` and then:

```
public class YourGameActivity{
    private MyClassThatImplementsIUpdateHandler mInstance;
    ...

    private void yourSetupMethod(){
        registerUpdateHandler(mInstance);
    }
}
```

It's the same.
Try it and see if it logs something, if for some reason you can't see the log use a breakpoint just to be sure.

Comment: I tried this, and it still didn't update (Which I suppose is to be expected because onUpdate is being over written) However the logcat doesn't output anything! Its as if the update method is being completely ignored :/

Comment: Well we are overriding the method but we are calling super.onUpdate inside it so it will work like if it wasn't overridden. I can't figure it out what's wrong because I've code similar to yours and it's working. Try this: engine.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);

Comment: Oh! Thats what super does? I'm sorry, I started self teaching myself java a few months ago and I still haven't learned everything. However registering the physicsWorld in the engine didn't work :/ What i'm going to try today is make a new project and test this and then move all the other work over slowly. Perhaps it's something with the way the application is setup.

Comment: Can you create an UpdateHandler and register it in the scene and see if onUpdate it's called? I've edited my post to help you test it